# " '}' expected near '=' " error appearing in a line that otherwise appears perfect

Tags: lua

When I attempt to run my script, I get an error returning on a variable assignment. I've re-checked my syntax many times and it doesn't seem to be a mistake I made there--I even had somebody else look at it just in case. However, the error that returns continuously points me to the syntax, and I can't seem to find a solution to this problem.

Here is the whole troublesome function:

```lua
    function registerquestlines()
       if player["testline"] == nil then
            player["testline"] = {"prog" = {true,false,false}, "quests" = {"testline1", "testline2", "testline3"}, "prog#" = 1}
       end
    end
```

Again, the error I get is: '}' expected near '=' on the line in which I assign values to player["testline"].

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A table initializer uses either an unquoted name or a bracketed expression, not a quoted name.

```
{prog = {true,false,false}}
{["prog"] = {true,false,false}}
```

Comment: Thank you, a more helpful error message would be something to be grateful about, too. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Lua's compactness carries a price:  it doesn't handle syntax errors well, since that would make its parser larger and possibly slower.

Comment: The message is clear. It expects that `"prog"` is the last entry in the table (at position 1) because `"prog"` can only be followed by `}` or `,`. It might have said `','` expected but would it more clear?

Comment: A `}` is **expected**, while a `,` is **optionally expected**. Following that order makes sense in most situations (e.g: `do a end` produces `'=' expected near 'end'` rather than something silly like `'.' expected near 'end'`.)